# Google Sign-in not working with Polymer on iOS

Tags: ios, polymer, google-signin

I've been looking into adding Google sign-in on my Polymer-based website using the `google-signin` component seen here: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin

When I attempt to sign in through Chrome in iOS, nothing happens. I'd assume this is a problem on my end, except that I also cannot sign into the Google I/O 2015 website (another Polymer-based website): https://events.google.com/io2015/

Is this a known problem or something that's just occurring on my end?

Comment: Interestingly, this problem no longer occurs if I switch to an incognito tab, or if I use Safari. I'll probably dig through mobile Chrome's settings later to see if I can find anything that might be causing this.